# LWC1057: label is not valid attribute for lightning:tab

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am not able to deploy lightning tab getting this error :-

LWC1057: label is not valid attribute for lightning:tab

Code snippet

```
<template>
    <lightning-tabset>
        <lightning-tab label="Item One">
            One Content !
        </lightning-tab>
        <lightning-tab label="Item Two" title="2nd tab extended title">
            Two Content !
        </lightning-tab>
        <lightning-tab label="Item Three">
            Three Content !
        </lightning-tab>
    </lightning-tabset>
</template>
```

Comment: is there anything else you have to add with this question? The code looks fine. How are you deploying? what you have in js and meta file?

Comment: I am deploying using VSCODE

Comment: What is the version of your component?

Comment: <apiVersion>46.0</apiVersion>

Answer (score 0):

You can try deploying LWC component using **sfdx deploy:lwc** command on VS Code terminal.

```
sfdx deploy:lwc -p lwc-component-folder-path 

sfdx deploy:lwc -p "c:/Works/Projects/DevCode/src/main/default/lwc/tabTest/"
```